# Play a video with Twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I'm building an app for Android to read twitter feed I got an issue to play video from a tweet. Currently my tweet feed is showing the thumb image and when I click on it, if it's an image I show the image and in case of a video I expect to be able to play it.

To load the image, I'm doing:

```
ImageLoader mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mActivity);
mImageLoader.DisplayImage(mPicToShowUrl, tweet_pic) ;
```

mPicToShowUrl is coming from :

```
mediaEntity.getMediaURL().toString();
```

mediaEntity is coming from the Twitter4j Status.getExpandedURL

tweet_pic is just an ImageView

The URL get look like : example.com/xxx/status/89284924/video/1 which is mainly unusable on any player as it do not contain something like xxx.com/1.avi

This kind of URL and ImageLoader allow to load an image. I'm looking for the same method for a video

I think the twitter video is more a streaming video

Any idea how to play a video from twitter in an ImageView or any other View ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look in the `extended_entities` of the response.  You'll see something like

```
"extended_entities": {
    "media": [
      {
        "id": 567972074346807300,
        "id_str": "567972074346807296",
        "indices": [
          46,
          68
        ],
        "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/567972074346807296/pu/img/uz53Ap4wEah7cV50.jpg",
        "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/567972074346807296/pu/img/uz53Ap4wEah7cV50.jpg",
        "url": "http://t.co/cGazAn7H3E",
        "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/cGazAn7H3E",
        "expanded_url": "http://twitter.com/katiemoffat/status/567972190639022080/video/1",
        "type": "video",
        "sizes": {
          "small": {
            "w": 340,
            "h": 340,
            "resize": "fit"
          },
          "thumb": {
            "w": 150,
            "h": 150,
            "resize": "crop"
          },
          "medium": {
            "w": 600,
            "h": 600,
            "resize": "fit"
          },
          "large": {
            "w": 720,
            "h": 720,
            "resize": "fit"
          }
        },
        "video_info": {
          "aspect_ratio": [
            1,
            1
          ],
          "duration_millis": 6605,
          "variants": [
            {
              "bitrate": 832000,
              "content_type": "video/mp4",
              "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/567972074346807296/pu/vid/480x480/eU1s1ig_skHgeRjB.mp4"
            },
            {
              "content_type": "application/x-mpegURL",
              "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/567972074346807296/pu/pl/tr7sF7aHBPOCuL8H.m3u8"
            },
            {
              "bitrate": 832000,
              "content_type": "video/webm",
              "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/567972074346807296/pu/vid/480x480/eU1s1ig_skHgeRjB.webm"
            },
            {
              "bitrate": 1280000,
              "content_type": "video/mp4",
              "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/567972074346807296/pu/vid/720x720/njkDGgpJBpsTjQD3.mp4"
            },
            {
              "bitrate": 320000,
              "content_type": "video/mp4",
              "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/567972074346807296/pu/vid/240x240/Gye4gcWtlJq8zXhF.mp4"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

So, you need to access `extended_entities->media->video_info->variants` to see all the different sizes and formats of video available.

You can choose between different sizes of MP4, a WEBM, and a stream - depending on what is suitable for the device you're playing back on.

(Taken from https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2015/02/working-with-the-twitter-videos-api/  )

Comment: Ok but using getExtendedMediaEntities or getMediaEntities or getURLEntities do not give me the info. Status from twitter4j only gave me this info. how to get extended_entities ? Thanks Terence

Comment: You need the latest version of twitter4j - http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/EntitySupport.html

Comment: Hi @Seb could you figure it out ? Can you help me to find video url with twitter4j ?